# How to handle a URI error in node.js Request?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, node-request

Trying to simply download a file with request. https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

It works perfectly fine, but if the url is invalid, the script crashes with the error: Invalid URI "notagoodurl"

How can I handle this error and log something and prevent the whole script from ending because of this error? I thought that's what on('error') would do.

```
//download file
request
  .get(url)
  .on('error', function(err) {
    return err;
  })
  .pipe(
    fs.createWriteStream(destination)
      .on('close', function() {
        message.channel.send(filename + ' added.');
      })
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to work out fatal errors, then wrap the call into a [catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch):

```
try {
  //download file
  request
    .get(url)
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Not a fatal error:', err);
    })
    .pipe(
      fs.createWriteStream(destination)
        .on('close', function() {
          message.channel.send(filename + ' added.');
        })
    );
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Fatal error:', err);
}
```